# Targeting multiple ID on a single css properties

Tags: css, sencha-touch

I have 4 container and each container has its own ID, is it possible for me to target all 4 ID with the same css properties without doing it many times, here is the example :

```
#Container1{
background-color:red;
font:200;
}

#Container2{
background-color:red;
font:200;
}

#Container3{
background-color:red;
font:200;
}
```

who knows maybe it could be done like this :

```
#Container1,2,3{
background-color:red;
font:200;
}
```

or anything similar with this, any help would be appreciated.

every container has its own id for a some purpose, don't ask me to put them under 1 id. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Container1,
#Container2,
#Container3 {
   background-color:red;
   font:200;
}
```

Add all seperate selectors as a FULL selector behind the comma.
For your own clarity I suggest doing a newline after each comma, so you don't confuse more complex selectors.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Dibbets answered, you can separate the selectors using comma ','. however, if you have to keep the different ids for other purposes, you can assign one **CSS class** to all the containers (for example class="container") and do the styling with class selector  .container{......}